# Do you need to pay taxes on cash poker games?

Tags: united-states, taxes, israel

My father is a poker player and only plays cash games, that is poker games where you only play with you own money (vs tournament where you pay a fixed fee and can win up to millions).

We currently live outside of the US. When we tried to cash in the certified check from the casino, the bank asked us the sign a paper which states that we have paid all the required taxes to the IRS. The truth is, we do not know whether we need to pay any taxes at all. Any help?

**EDIT:**

This is to answer the questions in the comments.

- We used to live in the US but we are not US citizen, neither do we
  have a green card or any other visas anymore.
- The bank is in Israel.
- The check was issued by the Commerce Casino, in California (greater
  LA), for an amount of about 100,000$.
- The casino did not hold any taxes and we did not sign any tax forms
  with them.

Comment: You live outside the US, but what is your tax status with the United States? Where was the bank? Where was the casino? How much was the check? Did the casino withhold any taxes? Did you sign any tax forms with the casino?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Check the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dad would have won money on the slot machines(And the amount was high), the casino would have given him a W2G to fill out right there and taxes would have been deducted. However, table games including Poker does not have any such rule. You will have to account for your winnings(And losses) at the end of the year. So, it is ok if you sign that paper, as you do not owe the IRS any money yet.

You will still need to file your taxes as a non resident alien at the end of the year and attach the form W2G with it and pay your dues.